# How do I install RabbitMQ?

Tags: server

Can someone please help me by letting me know how to install Rabbit MQ server...any links are heartily welcomed...

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a recent version of Ubuntu then there's a version in the repositories: try this:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

If this version is too old for you you can use the .deb file from the [RabbitMQ site](http://www.rabbitmq.com/server.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a recent version of Ubuntu, the most supported way to install RabbitMQ is via `apt-get install rabbitmq-server`. The downside of this is that the official repos are usually a few versions behind.

The version available for Ubuntu Precise is v2.7.1, [which is nearly 9 months old](http://www.rabbitmq.com/changelog.html), at the time of this writing. However, with the upcoming ([slated for October 18th, 2012](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal)) release of the next Ubuntu version, Quantal Quetzal, the [`rabbitmq-server`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rabbitmq-server) package is getting upgraded to [RabbitMQ v2.8.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/rabbitmq-server). This version was released on 22 June 2012, so it's pretty recent.

If you need a more up-to-date version of RabbitMQ, you can add the Rabbit MQ repo to your sources list and install from them directly following [these instructions](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html), or you can download the .deb file, or you can build from source.

I would recommend sticking with the supported repositories' version, but your needs may dictate otherwise.